# UK insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

15-20mm long.
Brown legs, head, casing/wings (no flight witnessed).
Black body with protruding back part.
Long antennae.
Very fast running speed.
Seemingly keenly aware of surroundings.

Is this some sort of small cockroach?[image: It's a tiny wine glass]
[image: running bug]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn yourself your first badge. Have a nice stay!

Comment: The photo is not very clear, the two spikes at the back identify it as a cockroach, a "forest cockroach", probably a "german cockroach", perhaps she is pregnant? I think they prefer slightly warmer, dryer climates than the UK, whereas the UK is mostly home to slower black beetles, elsewhere in europe, you can turn a stone over and there will be 5 forest cockroaches, which are very fast, and actually quite pretty and silvery in their own way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_cockroach

Comment: Thank you com.prehensible. In the picture of the German Cockroach with ootheca, the ootheca looks the same shape but different colour as the one I observed. This cockroach was certainly very fast. I saw her in the kitchen in the evening so that also fits what wikipedia has to say.